# Flutter: can I mix Firebase Auth with Mongodb Databases?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I must mention that I have no prior experience in backend development, and I know that questions on the subject have been asked before but I need a specific answer to this one.

I was wondering if I could use Firebase authentication to register & sign in my users and store their data in Mongodb?

If so, what am I supposed to learn besides "firebase_auth" and a Mangodb package to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Actually firebase auth will provide a `uid` after authentication that you can use in MongoDB to identify the user. To make it work you'll need to have your own backend or APIs that will help you retrieve the data from MongoDB after the user is authenticated via firebase. Whereas a backend or the API is considered you can use any framework to make it eg. flask(python), express(nodejs), ruby on rails, etc.

If you already have an existing authentication system and want to integrate it with firebase then firebase provides custom authentication, you can have a look at the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Follow up question if you may: I would prefer to use Python for the backend but I have no idea how to create a backend system and to link it to a flutter app. Is there any reading material or Youtube content that you would recommend I should check to have some insight on this?

Comment: There is plenty of content available. Providing a link will be difficult.I suggest you to refer multiple posts and videos so you get a better understanding of how to design them. Just search for rest API in python or flask with MongoDB and for flutter, you can use plugins such as http or dio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [fast-api](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) that makes your development faster