# Firebase or MongoDB for Flutter application

Tags: mongodb, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm sorry since I'm new to this.. I'm currently working on my startup which basically like food delivery system and I used Flutter for my app. I learned Flutter using Firebase as a backend. However, there are many sources that recommend use MongoDB as a backend database which I have zero knowledge about it. But I think that MongoDB just only offer for database crud operation. So I think for the database crud operation my app should use MongoDB. However, I think MongoDB is quite complicated when it involves authentication. So, which is better approach for me? should I use Firebase for authentication and MongoDB as the database or is it better to use only one platform for the backend whether its a Firebase or MongoDB? If I mix these two, does it will affect the pricing? Is there any ways that can make me clear which to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is an **open source NoSQL database management program**, which is quite **useful for working with large sets of distributed data**. It is mostly useful for big data applications and other processing jobs involving data that doesn't fit well in a rigid relational model.

It is an absolutely **right approach** to **use Firebase Auth for just login or signup and the rest on MongoDB**. There are 2 ways you can implement the Firebase Auth:

```
1. Using the SDK provided by Firebase
2. Using the Admin Auth API
```

You may select any of the above two approaches to save your UID on your custom Backend which might be MongoDB.

Contrarily, **Firebase can also be used as backend**. It provides the back-end server, a great database and analytics solution, and useful integrations with other Google products. Its free to use, affordable subscription options,  wisely designed backend solution guarantees project scalability and data security makes it a great choice for backend.

However, for the vast majority of apps and use-cases, Firebase is an excellent choice. You can start with its free tier and don’t need to worry about maintenance or scalability. It’s great for small to medium developers as it allows them to lower initial costs while focusing on providing the best user experience.

When working on a heavy real-time app like chat, or some other highly collaborative experience, Firebase is still an option, though it might be a bit pricey.

However, the recommendation is always to **consider your budget**, the **required feature set**, and how much **maintenance you’re willing to do** on your own before making a decision.

You might also refer to this [documentation](https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/10/23/feedback-on-firebase-in-project-start-up.html), which will guide you with the pros and cons of choosing Firebase as backend.

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter: can I mix Firebase Auth with Mongodb Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740911/flutter-can-i-mix-firebase-auth-with-mongodb-databases)

Check this similar post. If you still have doubts, feel free to ask.

Comment: already read that and i know it's possible.. my question is about which approach i need to use.. i find it hard to use mongodb with flutter... but people recommend it is better to use mongodb for large scale application.. however there is only bit resources that i can refer when it comes to mongodb instead of firebase for flutter...